# Restrict list permissions on Assigned not Created

Tags: 2007

I want to have a list restrict permissions based on who it is assigned to, not who created it so i can pre-populate data with a workflow. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with a SharePoint Designer workflow.

This blog will outline the steps:
http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/item-level-permissions-infopath-forms-sharepoint-designer-workflows/

Make sure your users have read access to the list.
Then use the workflow to assign permissions to the list item.

Answer (score 0):

Add a user field "Assigned To" to the list and configure the list view as shown below. This will only show items assgined to the user viewing the page

[image]